# Heroku does not download Dependencies

Tags: heroku, discord.js

I hope that you can help me. I tried deploying my Discord Bot on Heroku but unfortunately it cannot find the Discord.js module:

Error Code:

```
2019-10-31T15:35:21.569158+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-10-31T15:35:23.457399+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node Bot.js`
2019-10-31T15:35:24.147895+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-10-31T15:35:25.778631+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-10-31T15:35:25.838621+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715847+00:00 app[worker.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715865+00:00 app[worker.1]:     throw err;
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715866+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ^
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715867+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715868+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715869+00:00 app[worker.1]: Require stack:
2019-10-31T15:35:25.71587+00:00 app[worker.1]: - /app/Bot.js
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715871+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715872+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715873+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715874+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715875+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/Bot.js:6:17)
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715876+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715877+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715878+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715879+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715879+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10) {
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715881+00:00 app[worker.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715882+00:00 app[worker.1]:   requireStack: [ '/app/Bot.js' ]
2019-10-31T15:35:25.715883+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
```

The Build log:

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.13.0...
       Using default npm version: 6.12.0

-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules (not cached - skipping)

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
       up to date in 0.313s
       found 0 vulnerabilities


-----> Build

-----> Pruning devDependencies
       up to date in 0.275s
       found 0 vulnerabilities


-----> Caching build
       - node_modules (nothing to cache)

-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> worker
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 20.8M
-----> Launching...
       Released v27
       https://omghowadorable.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

And my package.json:

```
{
"name": "Date Bot",
"description": "My First Discord Bot",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "Bot.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "node Bot.js"
}, "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "11.3.0"

  }

}
```

I really don't know what's wrong with my package.json file that Heroku doesn't install Discord.js. Google wasn't really helpful this time as well.
I hope that you can help me with my problem.

sincerely Taki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going into the Heroku Run Command and type `npm i discord.js`